# What is the meaning of "typedef char CHAR[10];"?

Tags: c++, typedef

Came across a piece of code which defined and used a typedef it like below:

```
typedef char CHAR[10];
void fun(std::string s) {}
int main()
{
    CHAR c;
    fun(c);
 }
```

And strangely this works. My question is why define and use a typedef like this and how it works. In my opinion CHAR alone should not work, it should always be CHAR[10].

Moreover, if I change fun declaration to accept std::string& instead of std::string, it throws a compilation error. I am not sure why.

Comment: What new `CHAR` type? Please put the code in the question, not just the title.

Comment: "why define and use a typedef like this":  I would ask the same question.  But I suspect that somebody was worried they would forget the size of the array if they didn't include it in the `typedef`.  As it is, `sizeof(CHAR)` returns 10.

Answer (score 9):

This is a confusing part of C declarator syntax, and doesn't do what you think it does.

Throw away logic and follow [the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

#### What you think it does

Makes `CHAR[10]` mean `char`.

#### What it actually does

Makes `CHAR` mean `char[10]`.

That's why using `CHAR` "on its own" is perfectly valid here, if remarkably stupid. I mean, seriously, typedeffing a fixed-size array in the first place is pretty dumb, but naming it `CHAR` takes the biscuit.

Comment: It is not dumb to create a typedef for a fixed array. There are plenty of valid reasons to do it. I use several third-party APIs that do it, such as for fixed-length ID values, for instance. It makes the code cleaner and safer being able to declare variables/parameters like `ConnectionID connid;` or `DeviceID devid;`, instead of `char connid[...];` or `char devid[...]`. I would call it dumb to use something as basic as `CHAR` as the typedef name, though.

Comment: @Remy Yes, it's pretty dumb. Neither `ConnectionID` nor `DeviceID` look like array types.

Comment: They are string-based identifiers that have max character lengths. Like I said, it makes for safer and cleaner code when a user can declare a variable/parameter using a single distinct identifier type, instead of a raw char array and having to remember to use the correct length. If you don't like that kind of programming safety, you don't have to use it. But don't say it is dumb just because you don't like/understand it, it has a valid purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It's safety at the cost of dumbness. If you want a static array width _that's fine_ but make it clear. What you've done here is force people to remember to use the correct length, because it is not clear from "`CHAR`" how many array indices you have to work with. At _least_ call it `CHAR12` or something like that. And don't say I "don't understand it" just because I don't 100% agree with your viewpoint: that's absurd.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef char CHAR[10];
void fun(std::string s) {}
int main()
{
    CHAR c;
    fun(c);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void fun(std::string s) {}
int main()
{
    char c[10];
    fun(c);
}
```

Syntactically, that is correct code since a `std::string` can be constructed from a `char*`. However, that code is cause for undefined behavior since `c` has not been initialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now if I change fun declaration to accept std::string& instead of std::string, it throws a compilation error. I am not sure why.

Comment: That's because a temporary `std::string` can be constructed from `char*`. You cannot use `std::string&` for such objects. You can either use `std::string` or `std::string const&`.